# How to include asp.net core 2 dependencies in publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, nuget, publish

I have an asp.net core application. I publish the project to a folder and then sync the files to a linux production server.

All was working fine with asp.net core 1.x.

After upgrading to 2.0, using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.All metapackage, the asp.net core dependencies are not published to the output.
I use `<RuntimeIdentifiers>debian-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>` to create a self-contained publish, and nothing changes.

The linux server should not access internet and therefore it cannot download the dependencies.

How can I include all the dependencies in the published files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET Core 2.0 has a new `linux-x64` runtime identifier that you should publish for.

```
dotnet publish -r linux-x64
```

Comment: Interesting, using linux-x64 causes publish process to add files. But I'm still not able to run the published application. The error is:

`Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.`

I get the error even after publishing an empty console application.

Comment: that's strange indeed. does it work using the CLI to build&run a console app one the target server? (copy a "generic" linux-x64 distribution to the target machine and use `dotnet new console && dotnet run`)